# Unable to download Coderally

Tags: code-rally

I am unable to download the code-rally bundle from the website.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/code-rally/entry/beta_download?lang=en

It keeps giving Internal Server Error.

Is anyone able to successfully download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The download servers are having some issues at the moment due to a network outage. The team responsible for our download servers are already working on getting them fixed.

Comment: As an update to this the servers were fixed overnight and you should now be able to download the game without any issues.